# In-place editing using sed on AIX

Tags: sed, aix, portability

Is there any undocumented flag in AIX's `sed` implementation that allows for in-place editing in the same way as with e.g. GNU `sed`? The manual shows no flag for this operation, which is one of the most useful ones in other `sed` implementations.

Comment: If you don't see it in the man page, you can be pretty sure it doesn't exist. Just use `sed 's/a/b/' foo > bar && mv bar foo`

Comment: Use `perl -pi` instead.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas is Perl installed on AIX?

Comment: Just one thing to note regarding @terdon's suggestion: that may result a foo file with different owner/permissions than the original one.

Comment: @manatwork so will `sed -i` (at least on my Debian). It works by creating a temp file in the backgroud and renaming it to the original file's name so it will be owned by whoever ran the `sed`.

Comment: @terdon, it was installed the last time I used AIX 15 years ago (but then again it might not have come pre-installed on those machines) and had the `-i` option (which is where GNU and FreeBSD `sed` got the inspiration  from for their -i decades after `perl`).

Comment: @terdon, the GNU `sed` 4.2.2 I tried before my previous comment sets the ownership and permissions of the new file to match the old one.

Comment: @manatwork ok, very weird. The GNU `sed` 4.2.2 I tried here changes the ownership of my test file (permissions 777, in a directory with 777) to my user.

Comment: @terdon, probably my test case was too simple. I processed a file owned by user manatwork as user root. So changing the ownership had no impediments.

Comment: @terdon - yes, perl is most likely present on modern AIX systems ( I used it on AIX 6 and 7)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `perl` to do it:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/old/new/g' test.txt
```

It's going to create a `.bak` file.

Or without a `.bak` file :

```
perl -pi -e  's/old/new/g' test.txt
```

Or install `sed-4.1.1` RPM from [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible on AIX even with the `sed` tool installed.
You do need to use a temp file like suggested by **terdon** in comments to the question:

```
sed 's/a/b/' foo > bar && mv bar foo
```

You could also use `ed` which does inline editing.

Comment: Why would it not be possible with GNU `sed` installed?

Comment: well the GNU provided by AIX not the one you can compile see also ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Comment: `-i` was added in `sed-3.95` (2002). IBM offers 3.0.2, 4.0.7 and 4.1.1 AFAICT. Unless you get the older one, you'll get -i. Also note that you can get packaged version of GNU `sed` for AIX from other sources.

Comment: Well it means my admin system never updated since 2002 I guess. because even with AIX 6.1 I don't have the possibility to use that switch

Comment: @Kiwy, run away as fast as you possibly can. A system that hasn't been properly maintained for a dozen years... the mind boggles.

Comment: @vonbrand AIX 6.1 has been release in 2007 so I guess -i is not available since 2002

Comment: @Kiwy you `-i` is from GNU `sed` which you don't have installed.

Comment: @Kiwy - there is also pre-build GNU sed package http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Sed

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas on a fairly stock AIX7.1 machine I have access to, IBM's sed still does not support `-i`. I could not determine the sed version - it rolls up to the bos.rte.edit package.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes nobody said AIX sed supported `-i`, just that you could get GNU `sed` for AIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was reading between the lines of your comment from 2 years ago: "-i was added in sed-3.95 (2002). IBM offers 3.0.2, 4.0.7 and 4.1.1 AFAICT" the implication that you saw recent versions of AIX offering sed's that supported -i.

Answer (score 3):

To use a standard compliant `sed`, which does not have `-i`, to do in-place editing, in such a way that permissions, file ownerships and some other metadata are not modified and hard links and symlinks are not broken:

```
cp file file.tmp &&
  sed 'expression' file.tmp >file &&
  rm -f file.tmp
```

This creates a temporary copy of the file we want to edit, and then applies the `sed` command to this copy while redirecting the result to the original filename.

Redirecting to the original filename will truncate and rewrite that file, and since the file is not first deleted and recreated, it will retain most of its metadata.

Comment: fwiw, that's not what `sed` is doing. `sed` is redirecting the output to a temp file, copy through the permissions and finally rename the temp file to the original. That will change the file's inode and wipe some precious metadata but a) will not trash the file's content if the `sed -i` command was interrupted or failed b) will not trash the file's content if more that one `sed -i` was run on the same file at the same time. More details and ranting [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504812/308316).

Comment: @mosvy All true. The way I have arranged the commands in my answer will ensure that the original contents (at least) is still available in the temporary file if the `sed` fails.

Answer (score -1):

1. Define a variable and use a subshell to execute `sed` and redirect to a file.
   Very important use `"` (double quote) to protect the variable `$value`:

   ```
   value=$(sed 's/old/new/g' file) && echo "$value" > file
   ```

Or

2. Execute `echo` with a subshell you going to execute 'sed' and redirect to a file:

   ```
   echo "$(sed 's/old/new/g' file)" > file
   ```

Comment: That is just a convoluted way of doing what the comment by @terdon does. Better yet, grab the GNU sed and install that.

Comment: option #2 will most likely truncate 'file' before reading from it -- be careful!

Comment: @JeffSchaller : no, because the subshell should end before print opens its fd.

Comment: Use `print` with ksh or you will lose the line feeds.

Comment: @vonbrand : it avoids creating a temp file, and it is sometimes a requirement

Answer (score -1):

Or use a here doc with `ed -s`.
Sample short script - this hand copied, so may have a typo but the code is correct.

```bash
#!/bin/ksh
echo "test heredoc by adding def to a line with abc"
ed -s ./foo <<\END
1,$p /abc/s/$/def/p w
q
.
END

echo DONE
```

Test file `foo`:

```
This is the test file
qwerty
asdfg
AWEfgEDH
abc this line needs def at the end!!!

asfpgt
```

My sample output:

```
97

abc this line needs def at the end!!!def
100

DONE
```