# How to cut a file starting from the line in which a certain pattern occurs?

Tags: sed, files, ed

I have a gazillion files which need to be reduced in size. I found that most (not all) files have an end section which can be cut without losing information:

```
Data 1
Data 2
something_unimportant_here END DATA
Rubbish 1
Rubbish 2
```

How can I edit a file (end hence, all) by deleting the line including "END DATA" and all following, in-place, changing only those the files that contain the pattern, thereby minimising write access to the disk (many, many files and slow disk).

If possible, I would like to add a new last line to the file (my own end tag) so that the file's syntax stays correct -- again, only in those files containing the pattern.

I was thinking of using `ed`, like

```
echo ',s/END DATA/ ???? '\\n'q'\\n'wq' | ed "$file"
```

but cannot seem to manage the ???? part correcty.

Expected output:

```
Data 1
Data 2
NEW END
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like the sequence of commands you're looking for is

```
/END DATA/,$d
q
.a
NEW END
.
wq
```

or as a one-liner

```
printf '%s\n' '/END DATA/,$d' 'q' '.a' 'NEW END' '.' 'wq'
```

(You can replace `wq` with `,p` for testing.)

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
Data 1
Data 2
something_unimportant_here END DATA
Rubbish 1
Rubbish 2
```

then

```
$ printf '%s\n' '/END DATA/,$d' 'q' '.a' 'NEW END' '.' 'wq' | ed -s file
```

gives

```
$ cat file
Data 1
Data 2
NEW END
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I needed a `q\\n` before `.a` not to change non-matching files and write them, though (`ed` won't exit upon `q` after changing something).

Comment: (1) As far as I can tell, the **`.`** in `.a` is not necessary. (2) A slightly shorter alternative is `printf '%s\n' '/END DATA/,$c' 'NEW END' '.' 'q' 'wq'`.  Of course it has the disadvantage that it will try to execute `NEW END` and **`.`** as commands if `END DATA` is not found.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Thanks. The command needs to work both if the search pattern is absent and present. In the former case the file may not be written to. Will try leaving out `.` and edit as I find out.

Comment: @Ned64 `ed` works by first reading  the WHOLE file (either in memory or in a temporary file), modifying the data, and then writing back the whole onto the original (and replacing it non-atomically) even if you change a single bit in the file. I'm sure you're happy with this solution, but it does not match your "minimising write access to the disk" requirement. In general, it's not practical to use `ed` with large files.

Comment: @chepner No, I believe it needs a `q` before `a`. The file is not to be written to if the pattern is not found.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that part.

Comment: I believe that should be 'END DATA$' rather than 'END DATA'.

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Changed 1,681,605 files, roughly 120 GB reclaimed. @Kapil thanks, for me it worked well without `$` as the pattern is really specific.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do it by just truncating the file in place without having to write a new copy of the file like `sed -i`/`perl -i`/`ed`/`gawk -i /usr/share/awk/inplace.awk`¹ would do. With `perl`:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -exec perl -ne '
  BEGIN{@ARGV=map{"+<$_"}@ARGV} # open files in read+write mode in the
                                # while(<>) loop implied by -n
  if (/END DATA/) {
    seek ARGV,-length,1; # back to beginning of matching line
    print ARGV "NEW END\n";
    truncate ARGV, tell ARGV;
    close ARGV; # skip to next file
  }' {} +
```

That minimises the I/O as `perl` stops reading as soon as it finds a match, and  `NEW END\n` is the only thing it writes. It also writes in place, so the files metadata (ownership, permission, acls, sparseness...) are preserved and hard links are not broken.

With `-exec {} +` we also minimise the number of `perl` invocations.

---

<sup>¹ **do not use `-i inplace`** as `gawk` tries to load the `inplace` extension (as `inplace` or `inplace.awk`) from the current working directory first, where someone could have planted malware. The path of the `inplace` extension supplied with `gawk` may vary with the system, see the output of `gawk 'BEGIN{print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"]}'`</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the perl version, will vote after testing later.

Answer (score 6):

With `GNU grep` and `GNU sed`

```
grep -lZ 'END DATA' *.txt | xargs -0 sed -i -e '/END DATA/,${//i foo' -e 'd}'
```

where `*.txt` assumes all your files are in current directory ending with `.txt` extension. If you need to recursively search for files, `GNU grep` also supports `-r/-R` options.

`/END DATA/,$` range of lines to operate

`//i foo` here `//` will match the previously used regex, i.e. `/END DATA/` and `i` command will add the new ending marker as needed

as `i` command has to be separated by newline, `-e` option is used to separate the `d` command to delete all lines matched by the range

as an alternate, you can also use this, but only one file will be passed at a time to `sed`:

```
grep -lZ 'END DATA' *.txt | xargs -0 -n1 sed -i -e '/END DATA/{i foo' -e 'Q}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Upvoted.  Slightly prefer the pure `sed` (no `grep`) answer, and it was the first, so accepting that.

Comment: yeah no issues, I added grep because you mentioned minimizing writes

Comment: Good point. The same can be achieved by the extra single `q` in `ed`/`sed` which exits without writing iff no change has occured.

Comment: Does the `Q` version have any advantage over the `d` version?  As you point out, it will invoke ```sed``` many times (and therefore will do more I/O).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' not sure, I added that version in case there are too many lines in each file after `END DATA` there by helping when quitting early

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple and just use awk for the file manipulation part, e.g., with GNU find, awk, grep, and xargs:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -lZ 'END DATA' {} + |
    xargs -r0 awk -i inplace '/END DATA/{nextfile} 1'
```

or to print your own end tag at the end of every file:

```
... |
  xargs -r0 awk -i inplace '/END DATA/{print "NEW END"; nextfile} 1'
```

Comment: Yuck, that will copy the whole file instead of truncating it in place.

Comment: @mosvy "yuck" is a severe over-reaction. Every UNIX tool that does "inplace" editing (perl -i, sed -i, awk -i inplace, ruby -i, etc.) does that (except ed which makes a copy of the whole file in a buffer!) and it's what the standard advice for every other UNIX tool to modify the original file does (tool file > tmp && mv tmp file). The vast (and I mean vast) majority of people wanting to modify the original file are absolutely fine with it, it's a very, VERY rare occasion when someone actually **needs** the file truncated instead.

Comment: Except that you don't need any `-i` feature to truncate a file at some offset and write something there. The OP said "minimising write access to the disk", and your solution simply fails to do that. Whether it's really warranted to take the OP at their word is a completely different matter ;-) But people do have to deal with huge files, and simply copying them through each time they're modified is not practical, so this doesn't look like a made-up problem.

Comment: This is offtopic, but FYI some of the tools mentioned by you use different strategies to implement the `-i` feature, all bad, and not always similar to `tool file > tmp && mv tmp file` (with `tmp` on the same fs as `file`). For instance, `ruby` will open the file, unlink it and then open as output a new file with the same name. About `perl` see the links and notes [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504812/308316).

Comment: @mosvy I'm not saying it's a made up problem, just that it's an extremely rare problem that should be only be addressed when it proves to be a problem in a specific case, just like anything else performance related that requires complicating a solution that's extremely common, simple and perfectly fine in the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 2):

This `python` 3.8 solution is loosely based on Stephane's in-place `truncate` [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569129/21233) with a couple of differences
1. The code doesn't rely on external utilities for directory traversal
2. Files are memory-mapped for ease of locating the `END DATA` string

Place the code in a `.py` file and pass the directory name as a parameter

```py
import mmap
import os
import sys
from contextlib import closing

def yield_all_files(dir_):
    for root, dir_, files in os.walk(dir_):
        yield from (os.path.join(root, file_) for file_ in files if file_.endswith('.txt'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    old = b'END DATA'
    new = b'NEW END\n'
    dir_ = sys.argv[1]
    for file_ in yield_all_files(dir_):
        with open(file_, mode='r+b') as f:
            with closing(mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), length=0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)) as mm:
                if (loc := mm.find(old)) > -1:
                    mm.seek(loc)
                    mm.write(new)
                    mm.resize(mm.tell())
```

Comment: Does this process all files in the directory or all files in the directory *tree* (i.e., recursively)?  Either way, how would you change it to work the other way?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', as it stands it would process all the files in the directory tree. To change this to process all files in the directory, I would change the body of `yield_all_files` function to `yield from (f.path for f in os.scandir(dir_) if f.isfile())`

Answer (score 1):

Combining [Sundeep’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/569097/80216#569113) and [Ed Morton’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/569097/80216#569137),
but without `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' …(other criteria)… -exec grep -q 'END DATA' {} ';'  -a  \
                                -exec sed -i -e '/END DATA/,${//i NEW END' -e 'd}' {} +
```

- `find`, of course, selects files. 
  By default, it searches the specified director(ies) recursively. 
  To search only the current directory, add `-maxdepth 1` after the **`.`**.
- `grep -q` **q**uietly exits with a “success” exit status if a file contains
  the pattern being searched for (`END DATA`) and “false” otherwise.
- `-a` means “AND”, like `&&` on a shell command line. 
  It means “do the following thing if (only if) the previous thing succeeded.” 
  Actually, it’s the default conjunction operator
  between `find` predicates (tests/actions), so you can leave it out. 
  I included it only for clarity.
- So the `sed` command, which is copied verbatim from Sundeep’s answer
  (but with `foo` changed to `NEW END`),
  is executed only on files that contain the `END DATA` string
  and satisfy the other `find` tests.
- `-exec … +` causes `sed` to be invoked once with multiple files,
  as `xargs` does it.
  Note that we can’t use `-exec … +` with the `grep` command
  because it doesn’t allow testing exit status.

Comment: [ditto](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569097/how-to-cut-a-file-starting-from-the-line-in-which-a-certain-pattern-occurs#comment1058624_569137).

Answer (score 0):

Using awk to find the offset of the pattern, and `dd` to truncate the file at that point and append the new trailer:

```
# usage truncatoo pattern new_end find_args ...
truncatoo(){
    pat=$1; shift; tail=$1; shift
    LC_CTYPE=C TAIL=$tail find "$@" -exec awk -v q="'" "$pat"'{
           gsub(q,q"\\"q q,FILENAME);
           system("printf \"$TAIL\" | dd bs="l" seek=1 of="q FILENAME q" 2>/dev/null");
           exit
       }
       {l+=length()+1}
    ' {} \;
}

truncatoo '/END DATA/' 'NEW END\n' file.txt
truncatoo '/END DATA/' 'NEW END\n' . -type f -name '*.txt'
```

With an awk implementation which supports `nextfile` (`gawk`, `bwk`, some versions of `mawk` [1]), that could be done more efficiently by passing batches of files to awk:

```
# usage truncatoo pattern new_end find_args ...
truncatoo(){
    pat=$1; shift; tail=$1; shift
    LC_CTYPE=C TAIL=$tail find "$@" -exec awk -v q="'" "$pat"'{
           gsub(q,q"\\"q q,FILENAME);
           system("printf \"$TAIL\" | dd bs="l" seek=1 of="q FILENAME q" 2>/dev/null");
           l=0; nextfile
       }
       {l+=length()+1}
    ' {} +
}
```

```
$ file="a'b\$q  * r"; seq 1 100 >"$file"
$ truncatoo /7/ 'CUT\n' "$file"; cat "$file"
1
2
3
4
5
6
CUT
```

Instead of the icky `2>/dev/null` `status=noxfer` could be used with `dd` implementations which support it.

The quoting kludge and environment variables passing is a mess, it could use some improvement.

[1]: according to the GNU awk [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html), it should be supported in mawk too. However, the older version of mawk from Debian 10 does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time task, it is convenient to use `vi` for this:

First, locate the line with the needed content (by using search `/` or `?`)

To delete all lines following the current line to the end of file, press `d` `G`.

To delete all lines from the start of the file to the current line, press `d` `gg`.

Save and quit `:wq`

Comment: Thanks. There were very, very many files so I needed something scripted. The accepted answer worked well.