# sed -Extended RegEx question here

Tags: bash, shell, sed, regular-expression, replace

I feel dumb as a sack of hammers asking this here, but it's been a long day and I simply CANNOT figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a file; we'll call it `textfile.txt`. It's contents are (in this representative, but contrived example) as follows:

### FILE CONTENTS

```
SOME=1
TRIED="THEIR BEST AT"
INSERTING='A VALUE'
BE=4
```

Now, assume I have two variables `$KEY` and `$VAL`, representing, oh, we'll say the key and value I want to update in the file
(*Brief aside: I CAN guarantee that neither will ever contain a quote ["] or apostrophe [']*):

### NEW VALUES

```
KEY="TRIED"
VAL="THEIR HAND AT"
```

Okay, great. So now I fire off what seems like it should be a bog-standard regex replace (note that I'm attempting to keep the replaced value  enclosed in whatever *optional* delimiters it has encircling it presently):

`sed -E "s/$KEY=([\"']?).*([\"']?)/$KEY=\1$VAL\2/g" textfile.txt > textfile.txt`

### EXPECTED RESULT

```
SOME=1
TRIED="THEIR HAND AT"
INSERTING='A VALUE'
BE=4
```

### ACTUAL RESULT

*(an empty file)*

Okay, fine, so how about I target a NEW file instead of the one I'm reading from?

`sed -E "s/$KEY=([\"']?).*([\"']?)/$KEY=\1$VAL\2/g" textfile.txt > textfile2.txt`

### NEW RESULT

```
SOME=1
TRIED="THEIR HAND AT
INSERTING='A VALUE'
BE=4
```

Capital!

...except now JUST the second delimiter (the double-quote trailing `AT`) is missing around the value. I can re-use `\1`, which works, but I feel this is brittle enough without figuring out where I'm dropping the ball here.

## So... Question:

1. Why does my first attempt purge the file outright?
2. Why does my second omit the latter delimiter?

Note that I'm totally not married to this approach, and am fine with going another route, but if someone could PLEASE explain those two points AS WELL, I'd be much obliged. I woulda sworn up and down I knew RegEx if you'd asked me yesterday, but it's been a *minute* since I've used it in Shell.

I'm running GNU bash, version 5.2.12 on a 2021 MacBook M Chip Pro on Ventura 13.0 if that helps.

Comment: It works for me. `sed (GNU sed) 4.8`

Comment: Really? When you `cat textfile2.txt` you get both? Oh, gods, now I'm REALLY baffled.

Comment: @Quasímodo - Bro, you know how it is. I've been beating my head against a wall for close on an hour over this stupidity. And I KNOW it's gonna be something daft like that. I can't imagine (both files were created IN Bash), but... just to be sure, I ran both through `dos2unix`. No luck. Great suggestion, though! Didn't even occur to me.

Comment: Empty file is explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36263

Comment: I knew someone would have a reference to that part at least. Thanks @don_crissti! Although I'd swear there's a way to do that. Did I need to `cat` it out then pipe it into the write?

Comment: Unless your `sed` supports `-i` here's the way to do it https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/505600

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this took some digging. Thanks to both don_crissti (for pointing me at a solid rationale for the output being purged) and Gilles Quenot (for sending me off down one helluva rabbit hole to try and learn about `sponge`).

In the end, however, the net result was as follows:

1. The contents of the file were being purged because that's precisely the behavior that is intended when one is using the `>`/`>>` redirects. The redirects fire first, before the rest of the command, so i was wiping the file I was about to read to clean (by redirecting nothing to it), and then failing to write the results of the command to it on top of that (since both the file being read was now empty, and the redirect had already taken place regardless).

   The fix, in this case, was to briefly create a temporary file, then overwrite the source file with it immediately afterwards:

   ```
   sed -E "s/$KEY=([\"']?).*([\"']?)/$KEY=\1$VAL\2/g" textfile.txt > textfile.tmp && mv textfile.tmp textfile.txt
   ```

   This is an unfortunate consequence of MacOS using a less robust version of the `sed` binary that that found in GNU, and, while one can indeed `brew install gsed` to get GNU version, it cannot safely supplant the base version, which makes portability and future-proofing sketchy.
2. ...but this still left me with the Case of the Vanishing String Delimiter weighing heavily on my mind. Through the course of my investigations, however, I stumbled onto an interesting factoid regarding the use of expanding variables in a `sed` regular expression on the Darwin version of the tool: I had to wrap the variable names in an expansion, escaping the `$`'s.

   So, instead of `sed -E "s/$KEY=([\"']?)`[...]etc. the necessary syntax was `sed -E "s/\$(KEY)=([\"']?)`[...]etc..

   Further exploration ultimately proved that, if I simply escaped the `$` on each variable, as shown here: `sed -E "s/\$KEY=([\"']?)`[...]etc.

   ...I would also get the desired result, but a saltier Linux veteran than I intimated that the `$(VARIABLE)` syntax was safer in this case (though I've not the foggiest clue as to why).

Hope this followup helps someone else, should they find themselves similarly-stumped, and thanks again to don_crissti and Gilles Quenot for pointing me in the rightish directions! <3

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `-i` switch and you have `sponge` from [`moreutils`](http://kitenet.net/%7Ejoey/code/moreutils/), you can do :

```
sed 's///g' file | sponge file
```

This tool is especially designed for that purpose